# How do I condition the format specifier on the value of the argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, number-formatting

I would like to output the values as {:f} if they are above 0.001, say, otherwise as {:e} (exponentials).

I wonder if I can do this within one string formatting line, that is not conditioning on the line that actually prints, but inside it.  Are lambda expressions permitted?  (Side note: where are they permitted, really?)

FTR, this is my output string:

```
print("{:f}".format(my_float))
```

Comment: Mind the `)` at the end

Comment: You could do something like: `print(("{:f}" if my_float > 0.001 else "{:e}").format(my_float))`, but that looks kind of awkward!

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd use `"{:g}"`.  This will flop back and forth between exponential notation and normal float notation depending on the value:

```
>>> '{:g}'.format(0.001)
'0.001'
>>> '{:g}'.format(0.0000001)
'1e-07'
```

In contrast to `"{:e}"` which is always exponential...

```
>>> '{:e}'.format(0.001)
'1.000000e-03'
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding the condition into the format is one way I could think

```
>>> x = 0.0001276
>>> '{:{type}}'.format(x, type='f' if x>0.001 else 'e')
'1.276000e-04'
>>> x = 0.01
>>> '{:{type}}'.format(x, type='f' if x>0.001 else 'e')
'0.010000'
```

This is better than lambda, in my opinion.

To do away with if else, you can go with and or operation

```
(x>0.01 and 'f') or 'e'
```